# Troubleshooting "undefined columns selected" in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I was trying to remove all columns with a zero variance from my data, using this command

```
file <- file[,sapply(file, function(v) var(v, na.rm=TRUE)!=0)]
```

This command was working perfectly for my previous datasets, now I am trying to use on a new dataset and it gives me the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(file, , sapply(file, function(v) var(v, na.rm = TRUE) !=  : 
undefined columns selected
In addition: Warning message:
In var(v, na.rm = TRUE) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

The problem is I did not select any columns, I just applied the function to all columns! How come I get an error telling me undefined columns selected!
Any idea what could have gone wrong??

The data looks exactly this way

```
    col1   col2   col3   col4
1   FIA    3.5     2.4    NA
2   DWF    2.1     NA     3.7
3   LIK    0.25    2.3    1.38
4   JUW    2.1     4.0    3.2
```

Comment: Your `col1` is a character variable most likely, so applying `var` to it would return `NA`, and things just go pear-shaped from there.

Comment: @HongOoi, I tried removing the first column, yet got the same error message. Additionally, previous datasets which the command works for have the first column as a character. I really cannot find what's wrong!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The input file was a CSV file and read via the read.csv command, it had an extra empty column at the end of the table that was causing this problem, removing this last column via this command, solved the issue.

```
lastcol <- ncol(file)
file[,lastcol] <- NULL
```